# How to check for the existence of an IIS 7 web site via WiX 3.5?

Tags: iis-7, web, wix, windows-installer, wix3.5

*Note: This question can also be found on the [WiX mailing list](http://www.mail-archive.com/wix-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg42390.html).*

I need to be able to check for the existence of an IIS7 website based on the website's description. If the website does not exist I need to cancel the installation. If the website exists I want to continue the installation. I also need to be able to save the site id of the website so that I may use it during an uninstall.

For debugging purposes I have hard coded the website's description.  I do not see any indication that a check for the website is being made within the MSI log file.  This is the code I am using:

```
 <iis:WebSite Id="IISWEBSITE" Description="Default Web Site" SiteId="*">
      <iis:WebAddress Id="IisWebAddress" Port="1"/>
 </iis:WebSite>

 <Condition Message="Website [IISWEBSITE] not found.">
      <![CDATA[IISWEBSITE]]>
 </Condition>
```

Using ORCA I can see that IIsWebAddress and IIsWebSite tables are added to the MSI. The values are:

**IIsWebsite**

```
WEB:         IISWEBSITE
Description: Default Web Site
KeyAddress:  IisWebAddress
Id:          -1
```

**IIsWebAddress**

```
Address: IisWebAddress
Web_:    IISWEBSITE
Port:    1
Secure:  0
```

With the above code, the installation is halted with the error message "Website  not found". It appears that IISWEBSITE is never getting set.  Though, I know that "Default Web Site" exists. I know that I must be missing something, but what?

How can I perform a simple check for the existence of a website in IIS 7?

Answer (score 0):

I too had same problem.

I wrote a custom action to check the version of IIS from registry.

On the basis of registry value create virtual directory

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a custom action in Javascript to do this. If you are assuming IIS7, then you can use the appcmd.exe tool, and just invoke it from within Javascript to get the list of sites. In theory, it's pretty simple to do.  But in practice, there's a bunch of hoops you need to jump through.

Here's what I came up with:

```
function RunAppCmd(command, deleteOutput) {
    var shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell"), 
        fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject"), 
        tmpdir = fso.GetSpecialFolder(SpecialFolders.TemporaryFolder), 
        tmpFileName = fso.BuildPath(tmpdir, fso.GetTempName()), 
        windir = fso.GetSpecialFolder(SpecialFolders.WindowsFolder), 
        appcmd = fso.BuildPath(windir,"system32\\inetsrv\\appcmd.exe") + " " + command, 
        rc;

    deleteOutput = deleteOutput || false;

    LogMessage("shell.Run("+appcmd+")");

    // use cmd.exe to redirect the output
    rc = shell.Run("%comspec% /c " + appcmd + "> " + tmpFileName, WindowStyle.Hidden, true);
    LogMessage("shell.Run rc = "  + rc);

    if (deleteOutput) {
        fso.DeleteFile(tmpFileName);
    }
    return {
        rc : rc,
        outputfile : (deleteOutput) ? null : tmpFileName
    };
}



// GetWebSites_Appcmd()
//
// Gets website info using Appcmd.exe, only on IIS7+ .
//
// The return value is an array of JS objects, one per site.
//
function GetWebSites_Appcmd() {
    var r, fso, textStream, sites, oneLine, record,
        ParseOneLine = function(oneLine) {
            // split the string: capture quoted strings, or a string surrounded
            // by parens, or lastly, tokens separated by spaces,
            var tokens = oneLine.match(/"[^"]+"|\(.+\)|[^ ]+/g),
                // split the 3rd string: it is a set of properties separated by colons
                props = tokens[2].slice(1,-1),
                t2 = props.match(/\w+:.+?(?=,\w+:|$)/g),
                bindingsString = t2[1],

                ix1 = bindingsString.indexOf(':'),
                t3 = bindingsString.substring(ix1+1).split(','),
                L1 = t3.length,
                bindings = {}, i, split, obj, p2;

            for (i=0; i<L1; i++) {
                split = t3[i].split('/');
                obj = {};
                if (split[0] == "net.tcp") {
                    p2 = split[1].split(':');
                    obj.port = p2[0];
                }
                else if (split[0] == "net.pipe") {
                    p2 = split[1].split(':');
                    obj.other = p2[0];
                }
                else if (split[0] == "http") {
                    p2 = split[1].split(':');
                    obj.ip = p2[0];
                    if (p2[1]) {
                        obj.port = p2[1];
                    }
                    obj.hostname = "";
                }
                else {
                    p2 = split[1].split(':');
                    obj.hostname = p2[0];
                    if (p2[1]) {
                        obj.port = p2[1];
                    }
                }
                bindings[split[0]] = obj;
            }

            // return the object describing the website
            return {
                id          : t2[0].split(':')[1],
                name        : "W3SVC/" + t2[0].split(':')[1],
                description : tokens[1].slice(1,-1),
                bindings    : bindings,
                state       : t2[2].split(':')[1] // started or not
            };
        };

    LogMessage("GetWebSites_Appcmd() ENTER");

    r = RunAppCmd("list sites");
    if (r.rc !== 0) {
        // 0x80004005 == E_FAIL
        throw new Exception("ApplicationException", "exec appcmd.exe returned nonzero rc ("+r.rc+")", 0x80004005);
    }

    fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
    textStream = fso.OpenTextFile(r.outputfile, OpenMode.ForReading);
    sites = [];

    // Read from the file and parse the results.
    while (!textStream.AtEndOfStream) {
        oneLine = textStream.ReadLine();
        record = ParseOneLine(oneLine);
        LogMessage("  site: " + record.name);
        sites.push(record);
    }
    textStream.Close();
    fso.DeleteFile(r.outputfile);

    LogMessage("GetWebSites_Appcmd() EXIT");

    return sites;
}
```